# JQuery dynamic binding on table row

Tags: jquery

I am having problem regarding the bindings on table. The `id` is dynamic assuming the `event.id` is correct.

If I do it this way, the alert will fire.

```
$('#grid' + event.id).one("click", function(e) {
    $('tr').click(function(ev) {
         $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

In this way, the alert won't fire. I don't know what is wrong with this code, if I combine the id and tr.

```
$("#grid" + event.id+" tr").one( "click", function(ev) { 
         $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaking your code `$('tr').click(function(ev)` will bind listener to absolutely all `<tr>` on your page. Looks like you wanted to do something like: `$(this).find('tr').click(function(ev)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#grid" + event.id).one("click","tr", function(e) { 
         $(this).attr('id');
});
```